# How to prevent biometrics from being used for authentication to a web site

Tags: html, authentication, biometrics

I have a web page (basic html5 form) and I'd like to force users to enter their credentials and accept the terms and conditions (a checkbox).  Biometrics on mobile devices allows the user to quickly authenticate without addressing the terms and conditions.  How can I prevent Biometrics from being used on mobile devices?  Is this even possible?

Comment: What biometrics, and what mobile devices? Can you add an example of the form you have (the HTML for it) to the question?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking about autofill done by various programs. While I think it's actually better to let this happen, you can try to work around it on some browsers by randomizing field name/types.

Comment: I was wondering about randomizing field names and types as a possibility.  This is for fairly modern android and iPhone devices.  This has to do with our company wanting users to always check the box for accepting terms and conditions before being able to use the application.  I know this sounds a bit odd.  But legal would like the TnC's to be accepted every time they access the app.